# PySDL2 drawing order

Tags: python, sdl, pysdl2

The code below draws a black background, a white box and text. However it seems that the drawing order is not determined and I sometimes have the text or the rectangle covered by the background rectangle. I'm trying to understand what the appropriate way to manage this is?

```
import sdl2.ext
import sdl2.sdlttf
from sdl2 import SDL_Color, SDL_Init

WHITE = SDL_Color(255, 255, 255)

class Entity(sdl2.ext.Entity):
    def __init__(self, world, sprite, posx=0, posy=0):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.sprite.position = posx, posy

sdl2.ext.init()

window = sdl2.ext.Window("PySDL2", size=(320, 240))
window.show()
world = sdl2.ext.World()

texture_renderer = sdl2.ext.Renderer(window)
spriterenderer = sdl2.ext.TextureSpriteRenderSystem(texture_renderer)
factory = sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory(sdl2.ext.TEXTURE, renderer=texture_renderer)

world.add_system(spriterenderer)

sdl2.sdlttf.TTF_Init()
font = sdl2.sdlttf.TTF_OpenFont('resources/Helvetica.dfont',32)
text_surface = sdl2.sdlttf.TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, 'test', WHITE).contents
sdl2.sdlttf.TTF_CloseFont(font)

bg = factory.from_color(sdl2.ext.Color(0, 0, 0), size = (320,240))
Entity(world, bg, 0, 0)

c = factory.from_color(sdl2.ext.Color(255, 255, 255), size = (50,50))
Entity(world, c, 100, 100)

text_sprite = factory.from_surface(text_surface)
text_entity = Entity(world, text_sprite, 50, 50)

def run():
    running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        world.process()
run()
sdl2.ext.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of the `TextureSpriteRenderSystem` uses the `depth` attribute of `Sprite` object to determine the drawing order. If all sprites feature the same depth, the drawing order of them is undetermined, which results in your unwanted behaviour.

A `Sprite` with a depth value of 0 will be drawn below (or prior to) a `Sprite` with a higher depth value, e.g. 10. The default depth for each `Sprite` being created is 0. You could set your background's and rectangle's `depth` to a negative value in order to enforce the drawing order:

```
bg = factory.from_color(sdl2.ext.Color(0, 0, 0), size = (320,240))
bg.depth = -99 # always below everything
Entity(world, bg, 0, 0)

c = factory.from_color(sdl2.ext.Color(255, 255, 255), size = (50,50))
c.depth = -1
Entity(world, c, 100, 100)
```

You can read more about it in the [PySDL2 sprite documentation](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/sdl2ext_sprite.html).